# Sequelize Connection Error when creating model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I execute this program everything works fine:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const Conn = new Sequelize("data","postgresql","postgresql", {
   'host' : "localhost",
   'dialect' : "postgres",
   'port' : "1337"
})
// piece of code to be added here
Conn.sync().then(function(){
    console.log('DB connection sucessful.');
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

the Console logs: `DB connection successful.`
When I add this line however:

```
const User = Conn.define('user', {
firstName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
},
lastName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
}
});
```

I get this error message:

```
{ SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
    at connection.connect.err (G:\projects\investcrypto\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:95:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (G:\projects\investcrypto\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:123:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (G:\projects\investcrypto\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:71:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    name: 'SequelizeConnectionRefusedError',
    parent:
     { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1047:20)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1150:14)
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 1337 },
     original:
     { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1047:20)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1150:14)
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 1337 } }
```

Versions:
npm: 5.3.0
node: 8.2.1
sequelize: 4.8.3
pg: 7.3.0
pg-hstore 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the port `5432`. That is the default port for postgres. Make sure the database `data` was created by the user `postgresql` and that the password is indeed `postgresql`. Depending how the DB was created you might be able to just set username and password to `null`

Also, the [Sequelize cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli#documentation) is really helpful for doing a lot of the boiler plate code